# Convert Excel into HTML

Tags: .net, html, excel

I want to display my excel sheet into html view.

I tried using dot net (database method) and facing some problem. For empty cells I am getting default value (for example A1 cell is empty it display as A1). I want to display only data.

Any other easy way to do this?

Comment: Is this something you want to include as a function, or just something you need to do once?

Answer (score 0):

Easiest method is to save excel file as web page.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using a library, then it is very simple [FlexCel](http://www.tmssoftware.com/site/flexcelnet.asp) is my provider of choice.